# XSLT date format using substring

Tags: xslt-1.0

My requirement is to make a webservice call passing a date so that I get all records back that have been changed since that date.  I'm using Stylist Studio 2011 for my development.  I've managed to get a date minus 2 days, but it always returns with a time: i.e. 2015-06-20-05:00 but I only want the date without the time.  I have tried substring as in the following example and date format, but I get an empty result.

This code returns with time:

```
{<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:v1="http://types.msfc.nasa.gov/personnel/messages/v1/" 
xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="vToday" select="current-date()"/>

        <v1:lastChanged>
            <xsl:value-of select="$vToday -2*xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')"/>
        </v1:lastChanged>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
}
```

Results are:

```
{
<v1:lastChanged xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://types.msfc.nasa.gov/personnel/messages/v1/">2015-06-20-05:00</v1:lastChanged>
}
```

This is my substring attempt

```
{<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:v1="http://types.msfc.nasa.gov/personnel/messages/v1/" 
xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="vToday" select="current-date()"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vTodayTrim" select="$vToday -2*xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vTodayDate" fn:substring="(vTodayTrim,1 ,10)"/>
        <v1:lastChanged>
            <xsl:value-of select="vTodayDate"/>
        </v1:lastChanged>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
}
```

This is my result:

```
{`<v1:lastChanged xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://types.msfc.nasa.gov/personnel/messages/v1/"/>`
}
```

I've tried multiple variations of all this and the best I can say is I get consistent results.  I'm only chasing my tale at this point.

I solved this one on my own.  Here is what have working now:

```
{
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:mro="http://www.ibm.com/maximo"
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:v1="http://types.msfc.nasa.gov/personnel/messages/v1/" 
xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="vToday" select="current-date()"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vTodayTrim" select="$vToday -2*xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')"/>
        <v1:lastChanged>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring($vTodayTrim,1,10)"/>
        </v1:lastChanged>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
}
```

and I get back

```
{
<v1:lastChanged xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mro="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" xmlns:v1="http://types.msfc.nasa.gov/personnel/messages/v1/">2015-06-20</v1:lastChanged>
}
```

So my new approach since my application doesn't support 2.0 is to set the value in xml prior to putting it through the xslt as in the following (lastChanged tag near bottom of xml - this is output in the logfile):

```
{
<InvokeNASAPERSON xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" creationDateTime="2015-06-25T11:30:04-05:00" transLanguage="EN" baseLanguage="EN" messageID="1435249805139258092" maximoVersion="7 5 20130829-1209 V7510--1">
  <NASAPERSONSet>
    <PERSON>
      <DEPARTMENT />
      <DISPLAYNAME>MAXADMIN</DISPLAYNAME>
      <DROPPOINT />
      <FIRSTNAME />
      <LASTNAME />
      <LOCATION />
      <LOCATIONORG />
      <NASACENTER />
      <NASAFUNDINGORG />
      <NP_STATUSMEMO />
      <OWNERSYSID />
      <PERSONID>MAXADMIN</PERSONID>
      <PERSONUID>3</PERSONUID>
      <PRIMARYEMAIL>jreeve@cohesivesolutions.com</PRIMARYEMAIL>
      <PRIMARYPHONE>423 314 1312</PRIMARYPHONE>
      <SENDERSYSID>MX</SENDERSYSID>
      <SOURCESYSID />
      <STATUS maxvalue="ACTIVE">ACTIVE</STATUS>
      <STATUSDATE>2004-04-14T11:58:32-05:00</STATUSDATE>
      <STATUSIFACE>0</STATUSIFACE>
      <SUPERVISOR />
      <TITLE />
      <PHONE>
        <ISPRIMARY>1</ISPRIMARY>
        <PHONEID>82</PHONEID>
        <PHONENUM>423 314 1312</PHONENUM>
        <TYPE />
      </PHONE>
      <EMAIL>
        <EMAILADDRESS>jreeve@cohesivesolutions.com</EMAILADDRESS>
        <EMAILID>122</EMAILID>
      </EMAIL>
      <lastChanged>2015-06-23</lastChanged>
    </PERSON>
  </NASAPERSONSet>
</InvokeNASAPERSON>
}
```

My xslt seems to work when I test it in stylist studio.  Here is the current xslt

```
{
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:mro="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://types.msfc.nasa.gov/personnel/messages/v1/" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/mro:InvokeNASAPERSON/mro:NASAPERSONSet/mro:PERSON">
        <v1:PersonQueryRequest>
            <v1:lastChanged>
                <xsl:value-of select="mro:lastChanged"/>
            </v1:lastChanged>
        </v1:PersonQueryRequest>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
}
```

and the stacktrace

```
{End of input XML
[6/25/15 11:30:06:075 CDT] 00000120 SystemOut     O 25 Jun 2015 11:30:06:075 [ERROR] [MXServer] [CID-CRON-265] com.ibm.xtq.xslt.jaxp.HandledRuntimeException: [ERR 0641] An error occurred while parsing document: 'Content is not allowed in prolog.'.
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: com.ibm.xtq.xslt.jaxp.HandledRuntimeException: [ERR 0641] An error occurred while parsing document: 'Content is not allowed in prolog.'.
    at com.ibm.xtq.xslt.jaxp.AbstractTransformerFactory.newTemplates(Unknown Source)
    at psdi.common.xsl.XSLTransformerCache.createTransformer(XSLTransformerCache.java:96)
    at psdi.common.xsl.XSLTransformerCache.getTransformer(XSLTransformerCache.java:67)
    at psdi.common.xsl.XSLTransformer.getTransformerFromPath(XSLTransformer.java:143)
    at psdi.common.xsl.XSLTransformer.transform(XSLTransformer.java:129)    at psdi.iface.migexits.ExitProcessor.mapData(ExitProcessor.java:607)
    at psdi.iface.migexits.ExitProcessor.executeOutExitLogic(ExitProcessor.java:458)
    at psdi.iface.migexits.ExitProcessor.processTheseExitsOut(ExitProcessor.java:342)
    at psdi.iface.migexits.ExitProcessor.processExitsOut(ExitProcessor.java:157)
    at psdi.iface.mic.InvokeChannel.processExitsOut(InvokeChannel.java:329)
    at psdi.iface.mic.InvokeChannel.invoke(InvokeChannel.java:102)
    at psdi.iface.action.InvokeCustomClass.applyCustomAction(InvokeCustomClass.java:109)
    at psdi.common.action.Action.executeCustomClass(Action.java:399)
    at psdi.common.action.Action.executeAction(Action.java:311)
    at psdi.common.action.Action.executeActionGroup(Action.java:365)
    at psdi.common.action.Action.executeAction(Action.java:331)
    at psdi.common.action.Action.executeAction(Action.java:344)
    at psdi.app.escalation.engine.EscalationTask.executeAction(EscalationTask.java:1454)
    at psdi.app.escalation.engine.EscalationTask.executeActions(EscalationTask.java:1372)
    at psdi.app.escalation.engine.EscalationTask.executeReferencePoint(EscalationTask.java:622)
    at psdi.app.escalation.engine.EscalationTask.processReferencePoint(EscalationTask.java:520)
    at psdi.app.escalation.engine.EscalationTask.performTask(EscalationTask.java:175)
    at psdi.app.escalation.engine.EscalationCronTask.cronAction(EscalationCronTask.java:46)
    at psdi.server.CronTaskManager.callCronMethod(CronTaskManager.java:1590)
    at psdi.server.CronTaskManager.access$400(CronTaskManager.java:87)
    at psdi.server.CronTaskManager$CronThread.run(CronTaskManager.java:2156)
Caused by: com.ibm.xtq.xslt.jaxp.HandledRuntimeException: [ERR 0641] An error occurred while parsing document: 'Content is not allowed in prolog.'.
    at com.ibm.xtq.xslt.jaxp.ConfigurationErrorHandler.report(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xtq.utils.Reporter.report(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xtq.ast.parsers.xslt.XSLTParser.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xtq.ast.parsers.xslt.XSLTParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xtq.ast.parsers.xslt.XSLTParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xtq.xslt.drivers.XSLTCompiler.makeAST(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xtq.xslt.drivers.XSLTCompiler.buildAST(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xtq.xslt.drivers.XSLTCompiler.compile(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xtq.xslt.jaxp.compiler.TransformerFactoryImpl.createTemplates(Unknown Source)
    ... 26 more
[6/25/15 11:30:06:090 CDT] 00000120 SystemOut     O 25 Jun 2015 11:30:06:075 [ERROR] [MXServer] [CID-CRON-265] Failed to execute action  on escalation: {NASAPERSONWS} reference point: {155}  for object {PERSON} with id {3} 
psdi.util.MXSystemException: BMXAA4214E - An unknown error has occurred.
Please contact your system administrator for assistance. Gather the logs from the <HOME> directory and determine where and why the error is thrown.
    com.ibm.xtq.xslt.jaxp.HandledRuntimeException: [ERR 0641] An error occurred while parsing document: 'Content is not allowed in prolog.'.
    at psdi.iface.migexits.ExitProcessor.mapData(ExitProcessor.java:630)
    at psdi.iface.migexits.ExitProcessor.executeOutExitLogic(ExitProcessor.java:458)
    at psdi.iface.migexits.ExitProcessor.processTheseExitsOut(ExitProcessor.java:342)
    at psdi.iface.migexits.ExitProcessor.processExitsOut(ExitProcessor.java:157)
    at psdi.iface.mic.InvokeChannel.processExitsOut(InvokeChannel.java:329)
    at psdi.iface.mic.InvokeChannel.invoke(InvokeChannel.java:102)
    at psdi.iface.action.InvokeCustomClass.applyCustomAction(InvokeCustomClass.java:109)
    at psdi.common.action.Action.executeCustomClass(Action.java:399)
    at psdi.common.action.Action.executeAction(Action.java:311)
    at psdi.common.action.Action.executeActionGroup(Action.java:365)
    at psdi.common.action.Action.executeAction(Action.java:331)
    at psdi.common.action.Action.executeAction(Action.java:344)
    at psdi.app.escalation.engine.EscalationTask.executeAction(EscalationTask.java:1454)
    at psdi.app.escalation.engine.EscalationTask.executeActions(EscalationTask.java:1372)
    at psdi.app.escalation.engine.EscalationTask.executeReferencePoint(EscalationTask.java:622)
    at psdi.app.escalation.engine.EscalationTask.processReferencePoint(EscalationTask.java:520)
    at psdi.app.escalation.engine.EscalationTask.performTask(EscalationTask.java:175)
    at psdi.app.escalation.engine.EscalationCronTask.cronAction(EscalationCronTask.java:46)
    at psdi.server.CronTaskManager.callCronMethod(CronTaskManager.java:1590)
    at psdi.server.CronTaskManager.access$400(CronTaskManager.java:87)
    at psdi.server.CronTaskManager$CronThread.run(CronTaskManager.java:2156)
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: com.ibm.xtq.xslt.jaxp.HandledRuntimeException: [ERR 0641] An error occurred while parsing document: 'Content is not allowed in prolog.'.
    at com.ibm.xtq.xslt.jaxp.AbstractTransformerFactory.newTemplates(Unknown Source)
    at psdi.common.xsl.XSLTransformerCache.createTransformer(XSLTransformerCache.java:96)
    at psdi.common.xsl.XSLTransformerCache.getTransformer(XSLTransformerCache.java:67)
    at psdi.common.xsl.XSLTransformer.getTransformerFromPath(XSLTransformer.java:143)
    at psdi.common.xsl.XSLTransformer.transform(XSLTransformer.java:129)
    at psdi.iface.migexits.ExitProcessor.mapData(ExitProcessor.java:607)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: com.ibm.xtq.xslt.jaxp.HandledRuntimeException: [ERR 0641] An error occurred while parsing document: 'Content is not allowed in prolog.'.
    at com.ibm.xtq.xslt.jaxp.ConfigurationErrorHandler.report(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xtq.utils.Reporter.report(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xtq.ast.parsers.xslt.XSLTParser.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xtq.ast.parsers.xslt.XSLTParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xtq.ast.parsers.xslt.XSLTParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xtq.xslt.drivers.XSLTCompiler.makeAST(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xtq.xslt.drivers.XSLTCompiler.buildAST(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xtq.xslt.drivers.XSLTCompiler.compile(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xtq.xslt.jaxp.compiler.TransformerFactoryImpl.createTemplates(Unknown Source)
    ... 26 more
```

}

Comment: You have tagged this as `xslt-1.0` and your stylesheet declares `version="1.0"` - but what you show us will only work in XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Noted.  I took another approach.  The application I'm working doesn't support 2.0 so I had to take another approach.  I am now setting the date value I need using java code in the inbound xml.  I've changed my xslt as from this xml, I only need one value (to a query webservice) which is the date value and of course to change the tags to what the web services understands.  I have a handler that is constructing the soap envelope around the xml, but the xslt is failing with 'Content not allowed in prolog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This last approach was correct, I just fat fingered by filename when referencing the xsl call.   This issues is resolved.